# Codeigniter Bootstrap RESTServer - How to set up routing?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, rest, url-routing

I was doing this tutorial: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter--net-8814 (of course) and I found CodeIgniter and Bootstrap on a Github-Repo (CodeIgniter-Bootstrap). I just don't get why I cannot access my REST-Server via the REST-URLs. Routing is not very well mentioned by any Tutorial.

This is my Rest-Controller player.php in the application/controller directory:

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

require(APPPATH'.libraries/REST_Controller.php');

class Players extends REST_Controller {

    function index() {
        echo 'It works';
    }

    public function players_get() {
        $this->response($this->db->select('playerName')->result());
    }

    public function player_get() {
        if(!$this->get('playerName')) {
            $this->response(NULL, 400);
        }
        $playerName = $this->input->get('playerName');
        $this->response($this->db
            ->select('playerName')
            ->from('players')
            ->where('playerName', $playerName)
            ->get()
        );
    }

    public function player_post() {
        $playerName = $this->input->post('playerName');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        $player = array(
           'playerName' => $playerName,
           'password' => $password
        );
        // INSERT INTO 'players' (playerName, password) VALUES ($playerName, $password);
        $this->db->insert('players', $player);
        // On success, send back array with data
        $this->response($player, 201); // Send an HTTP 201 Created
        // On fail, send empty array
        $this->response(array()); // HTTP 404 Not Found
    }
}
```

That I wrote into the routes.php:

```
$route['players'] = "players";
```

This is what I wrote into the config.php:

```
$root = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$root .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url'] = $root;
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

I do not have a model yet. I just want to try out, if I can access the API via this url:

myproject.cloudcontrolled.com/players

. I thought, that at least it will show me the echo that I have in the index()-function. But all I get is a 404.
In the end, what I need to do is to send a POST-Request via $.ajax:

```
function myRegSubmit() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://myproject.cloudcontrolled.com/players/player",
        data: {
            playerName: $("#inputPlayer").val(),
            password: $("#inputPassword").val()
        },
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        // code to run if the request succeeds;
        // the response is passed to the function
        success: function (json) {
            $("#errorSpan").append(" It worked!");
            //$( "<h1/>" ).text( json.title ).appendTo( "body" );
            //$( "<div class=\"content\"/>").html( json.html ).appendTo( "body" );
        },
        // code to run if the request fails; the raw request and
        // status codes are passed to the function
        error: function (xhr, status) {
            $("#errorSpan").append(" Sorry, there was a problem!");
        },
        // code to run regardless of success or failure
        complete: function (xhr, status) {
            $('#errorSpan').append(" The request is sent!");
        }
    });
}
```

It is my first CodeIgniter-project and first REST-API so if someone could help, I would really much appreciate that. What did I overlook? I am sitting on this since hours!
Thanks a lot for every helpful answer!

Comment: you need to add player method in your controller

Answer (score 0):

in your code:

```
 $.ajax({
       url: "http://myproject.cloudcontrolled.com/players/player",
```

it sends data to 'players' controller 'player' method, if you want to use index mehtod change your route

```
$route['players/(:any)'] = "players"
```

Comment: Thanks for that! I played around a lot and this is just a leftover. Just for my understanding. If I enter in the browser myproject.cloudcontrolled.com/players/index it should return 'it works', or not?